# ng-leave class not getting applied

Tags: css, angularjs

I am using animate.css and Angular.JS for my project. I have created a codepen which you can find here: http://codepen.io/SassyCrafter/pen/NrRbmE. The following CSS (PS i am using SASS)

```
.form-message {
  position: absolute;
  .message {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    background: orange;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: .20rem;
    z-index: 1001;
  }

  &.ng-leave {
    animation: fadeOut 300ms;    
  }
}
```

If you have a look at the pen you can see that when the email is not valid, it fades in like it should. But when the email is valid and it is supposed to fade out it simply stays idle for a bit then abruptly disappears. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2**

- Found better solution:

*Replace -*

```
<div class="form-message animated"
  ng-class="{'fadeIn': !emailForm.email.$valid,
             'fadeOut': emailForm.email.$valid}">
```

*With -*

```
<div class="form-message fade"
  ng-class="{'in': form.email.$invalid}">
```

- Updated example
- Side note: Looking at my provided example, try pressing submit. You will notice that Bootstrap already applies a tooltip validation summary to invalid fields. Consider using this instead since it is built-in functionality of Bootstrap. [More info.](http://getbootstrap.com/css/?#forms-example)

---

**Update**

Created [working example from supplied code](http://codepen.io/CautemocSg/pen/xOEXvO).

---

`ng-show`/`ng-hide` applies `display: none !important;` which cannot be animated on.

The classes of `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` can be used together to accomplish what you want instead using `ng-class`.

*Replace -*

```
<div class="form-message animated fadeIn" ng-show="!emailForm.email.$valid">
```

*with -*

```
<div class="form-message animated"
  ng-class="{'fadeIn': !emailForm.email.$valid,
             'fadeOut': emailForm.email.$valid}">
```

And remove your `&.ng-leave` scss.

Comment: Thank you for your response :-). Sadly this approach just reversed the issue. You can have a look at it here http://imgur.com/OC60r8R.

Comment: @MaximilianLloyd I added an example from the supplied code - I cannot replicate the issue you are reporting. Let me know if you are able to or if it is in a certain browser.

Comment: I can see it is working in your example but when I copy it directly into my application It still does not work. I have created a gif here http://imgur.com/wtQjdUC.

Comment: @MaximilianLloyd Ok, the problem may be with where the `position: absolute;` was placed. I updated my example with moving that line into the `.form-message` class and it is working as intended in IE and Chrome now.

Comment: I have no idea what is causing the issue. Literally copy pasted your code without touching it and still getting the error i linked to in my first comment :-(.

Comment: I was changing the wrong input field in my application and that is why i was not seeing the changes, it actually works now. Thank you for helping me with this.

Comment: Is there any way i can prevent it from showing when you first focus the text field. Here is an example https://minglee.xyz/i/2016-06-19_23-49-15.gif.

Comment: @MaximilianLloyd You could put `ng-if="emailForm.email.$dirty"` on the form-message `div` - that would prevent it from rendering until the user has typed something into the input.

Comment: Yes, it prevents the initial flash when the page loads. But when you start typing in the input field it shows for a brief period of time before fading out. example -> https://minglee.xyz/i/2016-06-20_12-52-18.gif.

Comment: Have you found any sort of solution to this issue?